# Finding a relation between the integral bounds?

Tags: calculus

[image]

If $a,b,c,d,u_1,u_2$ are real numbers, what is $\frac{u_1}{u_2}$?

I get that $\frac{u_1}{u_2} = \frac{b}{d} = \frac{a}{c}$ but apparently this is wrong and the answer is $\frac{b}{d}$.  Why?

Comment: What steps did you take to get your answer?

Comment: So what I basically did was rewrite the integrals as 2*integral(0,a/u1) + integral(a/u1, b/u1) for the first equation, then 2*integral(0,c/u2) + integral(c/u2, d/u2).  Then by inspection I just set a/u1 = c/u2 and b/u1 = d/u2

Comment: I don't see why equality of the integral sums in your comment implies the limits must match up. True, IF they match one gets equality of the integral sums...

Comment: Jason-- I've put up an answer in which I give what seems to be a case wherein the bounds don't match, and even the "answer" you mention (from a text?) doesn't hold. However IF that answer holds it is also $a/c$ as you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the function $p(u)$ be the integral
$$p(u)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^u e^{-t^2}\ dt.$$
The two equal sums of integrals are then 
$$p(a/(u_1))+p(b/(u_1))=y, \\ p(c/(u_2))+p(d/(u_2))=y. \tag{1}$$
The problems "answer" then says that it follows that $u_1/u_2=b/d.$ The latter is equivalent to $b/u_1=d/u_2.$ Now *if* this happens to hold, then from (1) we can get also
 $p(a/(u_1))=p(c/(u_2)),$ and then since $p(u)$ is injective we do get also $u_1/u_2=a/c$ (your other answer candidate).

However consider the following example: We take $p(.5)+p(2)=y=1.5158...$ and try for another equation $p(.6)+p(k)=y$ (the same $y$ as above). When calculated this means that $p(k)$ should be $.911966...$ and we have $p(1.206)=.911906...,\ p(1.207)=.91216...$ and thus by continuity there is a choice of $k$ between $1.206$ and $1.207$ for which we have
$$p(.5)+p(2)=y,\\ p(.6)+p(k)=y,$$
where $y$ is about $1.5158.$ To fit this into the original setup we can then have
$$a/u_1=.5,\ b/u_1=2,\\ c/u_2=.6,\ d/u_2=k=1.206...$$
But in this example we do not have $b/u_1=d/u_2,$ and so do not have what the answer claims, namely $u_1/u_2=b/d.$